# Get records NOT between two date ranges (start and end)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a collection list with **Lastpayment** as a field. Using a date picker i want to filter by **Paid** and **not paid** within a given start date and end date.

what i have achieved is getting All paid customers with a start date and end date using

```cs
var filterDate = paymentData
    .Where(value => value.district != null && (Convert.ToDateTime(value.last_payment_date) >=
        Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) && Convert.ToDateTime(value.last_payment_date) < Convert.ToDateTime(enddate))
    ).ToList();
```

the above code will filter and give me all customers that have paid within a **start** and **enddate**.

However, my challenge is getting the **Reverse** which is getting all customers that have NOT PAID within a **start** and **enddate**.

Can i use a NOT IN expression in LINQ?. How can i adjust my code to give me the reverse ?

Comment: You have spent minutes writing this post, instead of put `!` sign before needed condition?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you please indicate how to use

Comment: `.Where(value => !(your previous condition))`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv sad i dint think of this lol.. thanks buddy